# MIDI SysEx utility for OS X?

Tags: midi, mac, osx, sysex

I've been using [SysEx Librarian](http://www.snoize.com/SysExLibrarian/) for...well, a long time now. It's functional but it's far from friendly and feature reach. Most notably: it's failed to keep up with the massive increase in transmit and receive speeds the MIDI protocol has gained from being ported to run over USB lines.

Is there a modern alternative to SysEx Librarian out there for OS X?

I need the following:

- Receive and save to disk blocks of SysEx messages as one single file (Record Many in SysEx Librarian)
- Receive and save to disk single SysEx messages (Record On in SysEx Librarian)
- Play back SysEx data saved in files on disk over any selected MIDI interface at modern speeds

And the really nice to have stuff would be:

- SysEx library view and navigation that allows for a tree structure (SysEx Librarian is one big, flat list of files which gets unwieldily when you've got a lot of files saved)
- Library search feature, especially the ability to search for specific bit-strings in files
- SysEx hex editor

Answer (score 1):

[MIDIox](http://www.midiox.com/) has some good sysex handling features: you can send, receive, and it has a small hex editor. But it has no library.

Comment: Looking for an OS X app, sorry. MIDI-OX is still Windows-only.